# Open external file with an external program

Tags: java, file

I'm a Java developer and I have a new question. I want to open a file with another program. I can do it easily with the `java.awt.Desktop` class with this code:

```
public static void open(File document) throws IOException {
    Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
    dt.open(document);
}
```

But is there a way to choose which program it uses to open the file? My program is only for Ubuntu. I want a list with all regular programs that can open that file (all options you see with a right click on the file). And if it is an executable file it should just execute. Is this possible with Java? And if it isn't, Is it possible with C++?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but probably not as easy as using the Desktop API, as that probably just calls `xdg-open` under the hood.

As the Desktop API almost certainly calls `xdg-open` under the hood (as most well-designed programs would do), you may be able to achieve the effect you desire by setting your desktop up such that `xdg-open` does the right thing for you.

If that's not sufficient, `xdg-open` uses platform tools to do its work, falling back to `xdg-mime`.  This reads `.desktop` files.  You can probably do the same...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I haven't a solution now. I can't find a way to do this in Java, and it should work on Ubuntu (12.04).

Comment: The Desktop API doesn't use `xdg-open` but the GNOME 2 libraries instead.