# Add external files to jar

Tags: java, file-io, external

I am relatively new to java programming. I want to know how we can add external files to our .jar. for e.g. i want to add a `.tx`t file to my `.jar` so that when someone runs my program, it can ask user where it wants to store that `.txt` and then copy it at that location. Is it possible to do so? So far all i have been able to find is [Open external file with an external program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688408/open-external-file-with-an-external-program).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAR files can contain any kind of file. For example JEE uses war files and ear files, these are really just extended jar files and contain various XML files in addition to the java.

You can read files from a JAR by using methods of any class

```
 MyClass.class.getResource("/path/to/myfile.txt")
```

Comment: thanks a lot...but how do i copy it to another location programatically?

Comment: I think you will need to do that the long way: open the file, read its contents, open the destination file, write to that file. Just standard Java File IO. I think alternatives such as spawning a process to actually us the jar program from the command line will be more trouble than using File IO.

Comment: I don't think read/write is the simplest way. You may try using OS libraries to do that more cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do this if you want..
By running this command

```
**jar uf jar-file input-file(s)**
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html